# Package bash-builtins: unable to run make sucessfully in examples/loadables

Tags: apt, package-management, bash

When I was wander through the Ubuntu 14.04 apt repository using `apt-cache search ^bash`, I found the `bash-builtins` package, and installed it.

After installation, with `dpkg -L bash-builtins`, I found that all it installed was some `/usr/include/bash` headers and a Makefile, a README plus some C code which looks like builtins under `/usr/share/doc/bash/examples/loadables`.

According to the README,

> On Debian GNU/Linux systems, the bash headers are in /usr/include/bash.
>   The appropriate options are already set in the example Makefile.

so I happily ran make and got a `config.h` not found error. By changing the `BUILD_DIR` in the Makefile from a non-exist local directory to `${includedir}/bash`, I was able to proceed until I got another error, reporting that `builtext.h` was not found.

It seems that the `builtext.h` should be generated by some `mkblahblah` helper program at complile time, but I couldn't find it without getting a tarball for the bash source myself.

The builtins `def` file was also missing, when I tried running `make -i` to skip all those errors.

Assuming that the package is useful, I do think the Debian and Ubuntu packagers have some ways provided for me to use the examples. Is there anything wrong in my steps, or is it a Debian bug?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I ran into the same issue so I would be curious to compare notes.

Comment: tl;dr - edit `/usr/share/doc/bash/examples/loadables/Makefile` and change the line `topdir = /usr` to read `topdir = /usr/include/bash`. Then `make sleep` for instance works fine. This is a bug in the Ubuntu/Debian package which needs to be fixed.

Mods should not have closed this. The Ubuntu package has a bug and your question was legit and clear (at least to me) and affected multiple users on the internet. I wanted to post the above as an answer, but I can't since mods closed the question.

Comment: `/usr/share/doc/bash/examples/loadables` is not intended for compilation, more as a reference. If you like to compile *loadables* you need the source. `mkdir -p bash && cd $_ && apt-get source bash && apt-get build-dep bash && cd bash-5.1 && ./debian before-build bash-configure && cd build-bash && make && cd examples/loadables/ && make && make install`